# Sorting new objects inside an list in Python

Tags: python, sorting, oop, object, binary-search-tree

I would like to ask for a bit of assistance.
I have a polynomial object that I already build mathematical equalities for it.
So for example, if I have 3X^3+2X^2+X and 6X^3+5X^2+4X, then P2>P1, all is good until now.

All these objects are put inside a BinarySearchTree, and with a def, I need to take them out in-order on an array, so as an example:
0
3X^3+2X^2+X
18
Would release [0, 18, 3X^3+2X^2+X]
I managed to make an array of all the polynoms in it, but I can't figure out how to either send them directly into the array already arranged correctly, or how do I sort the functions within the array?

```
class Node:
    def inorder(self, fin_list):
        if self:
            fin_list.append(self.value)
            if self.left:
                self.left.inorder(fin_list)
            if self.right:
                self.right.inorder(fin_list)
        return list(fin_list)
```

```
class BST:
    def inorder(self):
        if self.head:
            return self.head.inorder([])
        else:
            return []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have polynomials already in the correct order in your BinaryTree (you should), then you only have to read all the nodes *[in-order](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-print-nodes-of-a-binary-search-tree-in-sorted-order-8a4e52eb8856)*, also known as *in-order traversal*, or *left-node-right traversal (LNR)*. You can do that by changing your `inorder` function a bit:

```py
def inorder(self, fin_list):
    if self:

        # start with left child
        if self.left:
            # self.left.inorder() returns a list, and you need to add it to the existing list
            fin_list += self.left.inorder(fin_list)

        # then add value of current node
        fin_list.append(self.value)

        # finish with the right child
        if self.right:
            # self.left.inorder() returns a list, and you need to add it to the existing list
            fin_list += self.right.inorder(fin_list)

    return list(fin_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I actually tried doing that earlier and from some reason it didn't work.
On the other hand, I did find a solution for my problem.
The Sorted() function seems to work on objects if, like what I did, the programmer adds the math functions for the object themselves so that he'll be able to compare them. All I had to do is is add in the end Sorted(fin_list)

Comment: @D.Z. If you are reading all as in your example, and then sorting final list as an other action, you are unnecessarily wasting time and resources. The whole purpose of binary tree is such operations as reading (e.g. in order) fast. You are reading all data quite fast *O(log(n))*, but in wrong order, and python `sorted()` function works at best in *O(n log(n))*. So as far as I'm concerned, you are doing some unnecessarily work. Just read your data in correct order. You already sorted your data, when inserting it into binary tree. Btw would you plead consider marking my answer as correct?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and further explanation. I am still new to programming, so I will certainly improve (and get more efficiant) with time. Sorry I hadn't accepted the answer, but now it is :) Have a fantastic day!